# OBIEE Create Repository Failed

Tags: oracle, obiee

I want to create repository for starting OBIEE, but when I want to import metadata and select data source some error has been appear like below.
[image]

**I checked my connection pool in EM and was correct**

[image]

**and also check all data source connection pool in Weblogic and everything is fine**

[image]

**and tnsnames.ora has correct value**

Comment: OBIEE should not use SYS for its configuration. You should have created new schemas with specific suffix like DEV_BIPLATFORM and use this schema instead

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those two has an impact on the RPD creation if the RPD is created on some desktop using the Admin Tool. The sever has its own connection to the DB and the machine where the Admin Tool is running must have its own connection to the DB.

Also: Which exact version? What OS is your server on? What OS is your Admin Tool running on? Can the Admin Tool host ping the DB? Can it tnsping it?